# How to output different values under one Bluetooth LE scan?

Tags: c#, bluetooth

I have a skincare scanner running on Bluetooth LE, and the code below will scan the hydration frequency with a click of a button.

Goal: I am supposed to scan the skin once, and the program displays two different sets of data in text boxes.

Expected vs. Reality: As mentioned, I was supposed to print the different values in text boxes, so I declared two byte arrays and readers. I ended up with the second pair of data being the same as the first data, which I do not want.

What should I have done differently?

```
        private async void btnPair_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (device == null)
            {
                statusBox.Text = "Please, make sure the device is connected, and try again.";
                Thread.Sleep(200);
            }
            else
            {
                BluetoothLEDevice bluetoothLeDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(device.Id);
                statusBox.Text = "Attempting to pair with device";
                GattDeviceServicesResult result = await bluetoothLeDevice.GetGattServicesAsync();

                if (result.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                {
                    statusBox.Text = "Pairing succeeded";
                    var services = result.Services;
                    foreach (var service in services)
                    {
                        if (service.Uuid.ToString() == measureSvc)
                        {
                            
                            GattCharacteristicsResult charactiristicResult = await service.GetCharacteristicsAsync();

                            if (charactiristicResult.Status == GattCommunicationStatus.Success)
                            {
                                Thread.Sleep(5000);
                                var characteristics = charactiristicResult.Characteristics;
                                foreach (var characteristic in characteristics)
                                {
                                    GattReadResult notifyResult = await characteristic.ReadValueAsync();

                                    GattCharacteristicProperties properties = characteristic.CharacteristicProperties;
                                    if (properties.HasFlag(GattCharacteristicProperties.Read))
                                    {
                                        statusBox.Text = "Scan complete. Data are encoded into QR Codes.";
                                        recordDateTB.Text = DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd, dd MMMM yyyy");
                                        GattReadResult rResult = await characteristic.ReadValueAsync();
                                        GattReadResult rResult2 = await characteristic.ReadValueAsync();
                                        if (characteristic.Uuid.ToString() == rawDataHydCt)
                                        {
                                            //Convert.ToInt32(hexValue, 16);
                                            var reader = DataReader.FromBuffer(rResult.Value);
                                            var reader2 = DataReader.FromBuffer(rResult2.Value);
                                            byte[] input1 = new byte[reader.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                                            byte[] input2 = new byte[reader2.UnconsumedBufferLength];
                                            reader.ReadBytes(input1);
                                            reader2.ReadBytes(input2);

                                            int airHydration1 = decryptData(input1[0], input1[1]);
                                            int skinHydration1 = decryptData(input1[2], input1[3]);

                                            int airHydration2 = decryptData(input2[0], input2[1]);
                                            int skinHydration2 = decryptData(input2[2], input2[3]);
                                            //rawData.AppendText("Skin  Hydration Data: " + skinHydHex + "; Actual value = " + skinHydration + "\n");

                                            aHydFqTB1.Text = airHydration1.ToString();
                                            aHydFqTB2.Text = airHydration2.ToString();
                                            sHydFqTB1.Text = skinHydration1.ToString();
                                            sHydFqTB2.Text = skinHydration2.ToString();
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

                else
                    statusBox.Text = "Please, make sure the device is connected, and try again.";
            }
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried wait a small time frame between reading the data the first time and the second time?

Comment: In 99% of BLE GATT enabled device yo umust use value change notification instead of reading characteristics. Reading used for the characteristics that do not change too often. For the characteristics that provides real-time data you must use notifications.

Comment: @MikePetrichenko As far as I know, the device that I have do not have a Notify characteristic property. Tried to set the Notify flag, but nothing happened. The if/else statement just ignored it.

Comment: Indication? If also no, try use ReadValueAsync(Uncached)

Comment: @MikePetrichenko The engineer did implement an Indicate property. The issue here is that tutorials and examples for said property is hard to find online.

Comment: Its the same as notification (just different update interval and somne other non mandatory difference). So you must subscribe for that property changes. You can find more information about difference in this article: https://www.btframework.com/gatt.htm#CharacteristicValueChangeNotifications